# How to calculate the running difference of the same column in a table with SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure with data as

```
ReadingDate   Unit
01-05-2011    10 
01-06-2011    20 
01-07-2011    40 
01-08-2011    40
```

AND I want to the following result with T-Sql query. I am using sql server 2008 R2

```
  ReadingDate   Unit   UnitConsumed 
    01-05-2011    10      10
    01-06-2011    20      10
    01-07-2011    40      20
    01-08-2011    40      0
```

Comment: a little more information on where the unitconsumed column gets its data from would be needed to answer your question

Comment: oh, i see it's a difference calculation between the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
With tblDifference as
(
    Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by ReadingDate) as RowNumber,ReadingDate,Unit from  TestTable
)

Select Cur.ReadingDate, Cur.Unit, ISNULL((Cur.Unit-Prv.Unit),Cur.Unit) as UnitConsumed
from tblDifference Cur 
Left Outer Join tblDifference Prv 
On Cur.RowNumber=Prv.RowNumber+1
```

Plain and simple !

Comment: @Mohammad Shamim, my pleasure !

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in SQL Server using the LAG function. See [LAG function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).