# Running Difference between values of consecutive years

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I need to compute a running difference between InterimData values across different years.

| Year | Month | Provider | ProviderName | InterimData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 8 | 1 | A | 3866.666667 |
| 2022 | 9 | 1 | A | 3866.666667 |
| 2022 | 12 | 1 | A | 3866.666667 |
| 2023 | 3 | 1 | A | 7416.666667 |
| 2023 | 3 | 2 | B | 7416.666667 |

Constant = 12800

Expected Output:

| Year | FinalValue | Logic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 8933.333333 | (Constant-Distinct InterimData of 2022 Year) |
| 2023 | 1516.666666 | (FinalValue of 2022 - Distinct interimData of 2023 Year) |

I've tried using the `LAG` function, but it's not working out as expected. I am using sql server 2022.

Can you please help me?

Comment: What's your sql code? have you seen/tried [this 2nd answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6236867/1389394)

Comment: why do you even need LAG function for this. you are not subtracting from variable, but using the constant instead

Comment: COnstant Applies only for first year ... rest all years uses calculated values of Previous Years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAG` can't help you here because it doesn't carry information from all previous records.

You could solve this problem by:

- extracting your unique year-by-year values from your data
- using a running sum, that stacks up all preceding InterimData values
- subtracting your aggregated values from the constant.

```
SELECT Year_, 
       12800 - SUM(InterimData) OVER(ORDER BY Year_) AS FinalValue
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Year_, InterimData FROM tab) cte
```

**Output**:

| Year_ | FinalValue |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | 8933.333333 |
| 2023 | 1516.666666 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3WXNGopt).

Comment: Constant to be subtracted only for first year ..

Comment: Exactly, yet if you use the previous FinalValue for consequent output records, you're essentially inheriting that subtracted constant.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte and window function
I used recursive Query and everything is dynamic
first you find min Year  and calculate first formula to Min Year and Last formula to other Year

```
declare  @Constant int =12800
;with _list as(
    select *
    from (
            select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(Partition by Year order by Year) rw
            ,Max(InterimData) over(Partition by Year) as maxInterimData
            from Ta
    )a
    where rw=1
),
Years as (
            select   Min(Year) as minYear  from Ta
),
CTE as ( 
            select      e.[Year] as y,
                         @Constant -e.maxInterimData as  FinalValue,maxInterimData
            from _list e
            where Year=(select minYear from Years)
            UNION ALL 
            select e.[Year] as y,  
                FinalValue -e.maxInterimData as FinalValue,e.maxInterimData
            from _list e
            join CTE b on
                e.[Year]=b.y +1 )
select y,FinalValue from CTE
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
drop TABLE if exists  Ta
create table Ta(
Year    smallint ,Month smallint,Provider smallint, ProviderName varchar(100),  InterimData decimal(38,6)
)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2022, 8, 1,'A',3866.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2022, 9,1,'A',3866.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData)VALUES(2022,12,1,'A',3866.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2023,3,1, 'A',7416.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2023,3, 2, 'B', 7416.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2024,3, 2, 'B', 7416.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2025,3, 2, 'A', 7416.666667)
INSERT INTO Ta(Year,Month,Provider,ProviderName,InterimData) VALUES(2025,3, 2, 'B', 7416.666667)
```

Comment: THis works only for two years..IF the count of years is more .. then it wil not give the expected result

Comment: I edited my code,please check my code and tell me your result

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as ( 
  select year, max(InterimData) val, row_number() over (order by year) rn
  from table_name group by year),
rec(year, val, rn) as (
  select year, 12800 - val, rn from t where rn = 1 union all
  select t.year, rec.val - t.val, t.rn from t join rec on rec.rn + 1 = t.rn )
select year, val from rec
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mAR7LuPf)

1. Take distinct values per year, here done with aggregation and sum() in subquery `t`, also add row numbers,
2. Use simple [recursive query](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/), in first row subtract from constant value, in next row previous minus current value.